# how to delete one row instead of all rows

Tags: php, mysql

How do I delete one single row with the code that I have. It allows me to delete all rows instead of one single row with an ID not sure what im doing wrong not sure if its the loop I have or what.

```
<?php
include_once('dbconnect.php');
echo "<form action='delete.php' method='post' id = 'deleteForm'>";

$sqlARTICLEQuery = "SELECT * FROM articles where pageId=$paqueryRow[pageId] order by articleId";
    $articlequeryResult = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlARTICLEQuery);
    while ($articlequeryRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($articlequeryResult))
    { echo "<input type = 'radio' name = '$articlequeryRow[articleId]' method = 'post'>".$articlequeryRow['articleId']."&nbsp".$articlequeryRow['articleTitle']."&nbsp";
        echo "<input name='ARTSubmit' type='submit' value='delete record' /><br/>";
        if (isset($_POST['ARTSubmit'])){
            $artDeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM articles where pageId = $paqueryRow[pageId] AND articleId=$articlequeryRow[articleId].";

            if(mysqli_query($conn, $artDeleteQuery)){
                echo "Record deleted successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error ($conn);
            }
        }
$sqlTEXTQuery = "SELECT * FROM text where articleId=$articlequeryRow[articleId] order by textId";
$textqueryResult = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlTEXTQuery);                   
while ($textqueryRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($textqueryResult))
        {
            echo "<input type = 'radio' name = '$textqueryRow[textId]' method = 'post'>".$textqueryRow['textId']."&nbsp".$textqueryRow['textTitle']."&nbsp"; //how can I print articles.pageId to match with pages.pageId
            echo "<input name='TEXTSubmit' type='submit' value='delete record' /><br/>";
            if (isset($_POST['TEXTSubmit'])){
                $textDeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM text where articleId = $articlequeryRow[articleId] AND textId = $textqueryRow[textId].";

                if(mysqli_query($conn, $textDeleteQuery)){

                    echo "Record deleted successfully";
                } else {
                    echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error ($conn);
                }
            }echo "<br />"
        }echo "<br />"
}echo "</form>"
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Apart from severe sql injection attacks, you should be fine

Comment: There are also syntax errors in his code. In the second line you need a double quote at the end followed by a semicolon.

Comment: `id desc LIMIT 1 || id asc LIMIT 1`(As per your use) At the end of query.

Comment: Think about refactoring the whole code. This code looks like a mess, is hardly readable on the first glance and has as mentioned by Akintunde severe sql injection risks. 

Also you use loops which are not mandatory to perform bulk deletes and not for single deletes. If you want to delete only one entry you can just use the query 'DELETE FROM articles WHERE ID = X'  and for multiple you could use 'DELETE FROM articles WHERE ID in (X,Y,Z)'.

Comment: Not sure what i'm doing wrong I use the while loops to output the data from database. I'm thinking that the if(isset) statements will allow me to pick the id from the while loop and allow me to delete the corresponding ID. I want to be able to output from my database and delete singularly the ID's

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a end quote on line 2 from the echo.  and i removed the dot behind you query on line 20 your delete line. hope it helps.

```
include_once('dbconnect.php');
echo "<form action='delete.php' method='post' id = 'deleteForm'>";

$sqlARTICLEQuery = "SELECT * FROM articles where pageId=$paqueryRow[pageId] order by articleId";
$articlequeryResult = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlARTICLEQuery);
while ($articlequeryRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($articlequeryResult))
{ echo "<input type = 'radio' name = '$articlequeryRow[articleId]' method = 'post'>".$articlequeryRow['articleId']."&nbsp".$articlequeryRow['articleTitle']."&nbsp";
    echo "<input name='ARTSubmit' type='submit' value='delete record' /><br/>";
    if (isset($_POST['ARTSubmit'])){
        $artDeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM articles where pageId = $paqueryRow[pageId] AND articleId=$articlequeryRow[articleId].";

        if(mysqli_query($conn, $artDeleteQuery)){
            echo "Record deleted successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error ($conn);
        }
    }
$sqlTEXTQuery = "SELECT * FROM text where articleId=$articlequeryRow[articleId] order by textId";
$textqueryResult = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlTEXTQuery);                   
while ($textqueryRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($textqueryResult))
    {
        echo "<input type = 'radio' name = '$textqueryRow[textId]' method = 'post'>".$textqueryRow['textId']."&nbsp".$textqueryRow['textTitle']."&nbsp";         //how can I print articles.pageId to match with pages.pageId
        echo "<input name='TEXTSubmit' type='submit' value='delete   record' /><br/>";
        if (isset($_POST['TEXTSubmit'])){
            $textDeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM text where articleId = $articlequeryRow[articleId] AND textId = $textqueryRow[textId].";

            if(mysqli_query($conn, $textDeleteQuery)){

                echo "Record deleted successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error ($conn);
            }
        }echo "<br />"
    }echo "<br />"
}echo "</form>"
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: I would look into prepared statements for security.